# Visual Studio 2015 - New Project Windows Obscuring Details

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2015

Hi I have Visual Studio 2015 - And when I try to create a new Windows Form Application - both the Location, SolutionName, CreateDirectoryforSolution box and Add to Source Control are missing - Yet if I select a "Telerik" type or other types it shows - I've checked on my colleagues machine and his works as predicted. ie Shows the other project elements. 
Two images below - Any clues? Resizing the frame does not help.

Thanks

[image: New Project With Missing Details]

and with the correct details:-
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio allows you to create new projects without having to save them (temporary projects).

If you create a new Forms application, it will generate all the files etc. If you wish to save, click the Save menu option and the following window is shown:

[image: Screen shot of Save Project window]

You can control this behaviour via the options:

[image: Visual Studio options]

1. On the Tools menu, click Options.
2. Expand the Projects and Solutions node, and select the General node.
3. Make sure Save new projects when created is cleared, if you want to allow temporary projects; otherwise, make sure it's checked to be prompted for location and solution name when creating a new project.
4. Click OK.

With the `Save new projects` option is checked, you'll be prompted for a Name, Location and Solution Name when selecting the project type, as per the screenshot below.

[image: New Project Window]

This MSDN article: [Temporary Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yx39k28.aspx) provides a fuller explanation on the subject.

Comment: Thanks Diamond GeezeR - All sorted now - Was driving me bonkers.